# Using emails in like statements not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

Do you need to escape characters when searching for emails? I have following value in a subject column:

```
XX Operation <operation@xxx.com>,Info XX<info@xxx.com>
```

Following does not return any results:

```
select top 10 * from messages where subject like '%operation@xxx.com%'
```

But I get no results.

[image]

Comment: [Works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=faec600eb07a55dc34e9a21ceb76de35) when I try it - please create a [MRE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data seems to work:

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(MAX) = 'XX Operation operation@xxx.com,Info XXinfo@xxx.com'

SELECT IIF(@A like '%operation@xxx.com%', 1, 0); -- give 1
```

The `.` is not a [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) character and there is no need to escape it. I will first check the collation of your database and then your column. For example, the following is not a match:

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(MAX) = 'XX Operation operation@xxx.com,Info XXinfo@xxx.com'

SELECT IIF(@A like '%Operation@xxx.com%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS , 1, 0)
```

---

The issue was caused by hidden chars.